# Django Query Relations Behaviour

Tags: django, django-queryset

Okay is there a way to filter the objects so that you only get records with associated records. Is it a right join maybe?

Basically, I only want to select records from A that B has a foreign key for whilst using a WHERE clause on B. Am i making it sound more complicated than it is? I don't need the records from B, just the A; maybe a subquery?

I'm relatively new to Django's queries and i've only just done some of the simpler stuff.

Comment: would you give a specified example?

Comment: Filter object A so that it only gets the records with a relation to B and B is the model with the foreign key to A

Comment: there are two ways to do it (although I cannot recall the second one exactly). The easy way is to do A.objects.filter(id__in = B.objects.filter(your custom filter).values_list('a', flat = True)). It is kind of subquery. I will try to recall second way.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but if I understand you correctly it would work like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    some_field = models.IntegerField()

a.filter(b__some_field=5).distinct()
```

This `JOINs` the two tables and filters on `b`'s `some_field`. Then `distinct()` makes sure that only unique `a`s are returned. See the documentation on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was a lot more simpler than I initially thought. I didn't know you could filter associated models so easily. Here's what I ended up with:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

a.filter(b__location=request.user.profile.location)
```